# hashtable: how to understand this implementation of hashtable based on List in STL

Tags: c++, list, hashtable

I'm learning to build a hashtable with c++. And find this post: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-hashing-chaining/.

It implemented a simple and basic version of hashtable (not production level) with chaining to fix hash collision issue.

I followed the post and run it locally and it works as expected. The implementation is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Hash {
    int BUCKET;
    list<int> *table; // confusing point1 

    public:
        Hash(int V);

        void insertItem(int key);

        void deleteItem(int key);

        int hashFunction(int x) {
            return (x % BUCKET);
        }

        void displayHash();
};

Hash::Hash(int b) {
    this->BUCKET = b;
    table = new list<int>[BUCKET]; // confusing point2
}

void Hash::insertItem(int key) {
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    table[index].push_back(key);
}

void Hash::deleteItem(int key) {
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    list <int> :: iterator i;
    for (i = table[index].begin(); i != table[index].end(); i++) {
        if (*i ==  key) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i != table[index].end()) {
        table[index].erase(i);
    }
}

void Hash:: displayHash() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BUCKET; i++) {
        cout << i;
        for (auto x : table[i]) {
            cout << "-->" << x;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Driver program  
int main() 
{ 
  // array that contains keys to be mapped 
  int a[] = {15, 11, 27, 8, 12}; 
  int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); 

  // insert the keys into the hash table 
  Hash h(7);   // 7 is count of buckets in 
               // hash table 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
    h.insertItem(a[i]);   

  // delete 12 from hash table 
  h.deleteItem(12); 

  // display the Hash table 
  h.displayHash(); 

  return 0; 
}
```

I have two confusing points about this implementation:

- `list<int> *table` : table should be buckets array. Right? `list<int>
  *` should be list type pointer, right? How it works here?
- `table = new list<int>[BUCKET]`: I checked many list related
  documents. but didn't find how the `[]` works?

Comment: You can't find much on this because no one sane makes a dynamic array of `std::list` array without a really, really good reason. There's no reason here. Whoever made this example simplified it too much and wrote a memory-leak factory. Apply the trivial fix for that and it becomes a [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)-violating timebomb. Replace the pointer with a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). That said, this is just bog-standard making of a dynamic array. It's no different from `int * p; p = new int[size];`

Comment: I implore you to abandon learning C++ from Internet tutorials. They are too hit-and-miss. This example is a miss. In order to learn from the Internet, you have to know how to recognize bad information. [Start with a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). The book costs money, but it will save you a ton of time by teaching the basics,how to avoid stuff that looks like the basics, but isn't, terminology you can use to perform effective searches, and most importantly what good examples look like.

Comment: yes, bad information is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `list<int> *table` : table should be buckets array. Right? `list<int>*` should be list type pointer, right? How it works here?

In this awful code, `table` is a pointer to a `list<int>`, but when you have a pointer to an item and *happen to know* there's an array of contiguous elements there, you can index it like an array, so `table[0]` is the same as `*table`, `table[1]` would be the next `list<int>` in memory after `table[0]` and so on.

> `table = new list<int>[BUCKET]`: I checked many list related documents. but didn't find how the [] works?

This is the initialisation that creates an array of `list<int>` objects and saves their address in `table`, so we do indeed "happen to know" that the array is there and can index `table` as an array.  For example, inside the `displayHash` function you see `for (auto x : table[i])` - that means `x` takes on each value from the `list<int>` at bucket `i` which is `table[i]`.

The code also needs a destructor to `delete[] table`, or all the memory will be leaked when the `Hash` object's default destructor runs without doing any clean-up.

You should also be aware that it lets you insert multiple copies of the same key - a proper and full implementation of this functionality is be [`std::unordered_multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset).

Cleaning it up minimally - without taking the next steps to use templates to let you use it for other types, add iterators etc.:

```
class Hash {
    vector<list<int>> table_;

  public:
    Hash(size_t size) : table_{size} { }

    void insert(int key) {
        table_[bucket(key)].push_back(key);
    }

    void erase(int key) {
        auto& bucket_list = table_[bucket(key)];
        auto it = find(bucket_list.begin(), bucket_list.end(), key);
        if (it != bucket_list.end())
            bucket_list.erase(it);
    }

    int bucket(int key) const {
        return hash(key) % table_.size();
    }

    static int hash(int key) {
        return key;
    }

    // example usage: my_hash.display(std::cout);
    void display(std::ostream& os) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < table_.size_; ++i) {
            os << '[' << i << ']';
            for (auto x : table[i])
                 os << "-->" << x;
            os << '\n';
        }
    }

    // extensions ===================================
    bool contains(int key) const {
        auto& bucket_list = table_[bucket(key)];
        auto it = find(bucket_list.begin(), bucket_list.end(), key);
        return it != bucket_list.end();
    }

    // example usage:
    //   my_hash.visit([](auto key) { std::cout << key << '\n'; });
    template <typename Functor)
    void visit(Functor functor) const {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < table_.size_; ++i)
            for (auto x : table[i])
                 functor(x);
    }
};
```